# immutable strings, typeerror: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I am using someone else code to make a Cipher solver but it gives me

```
typeerror: 'str' object does not support item assignment"
```

at

```
key[keyIndex] = cipherletter
```

Is there a way to keep the same meaning with the error? :)

```
def decryptWithCipherletterMapping(ciphertext, letterMapping):
# Return a string of the ciphertext decrypted with the letter mapping,
# with any ambiguous decrypted letters replaced with an _ underscore.

# First create a simple sub key from the letterMapping mapping.
    key = ['x'] * len(LETTERS)
    for cipherletter in LETTERS:
        if len(letterMapping[cipherletter]) == 1:
# If there's only one letter, add it to the key.
            keyIndex = LETTERS.find(letterMapping[cipherletter][0])
            key[keyIndex] = cipherletter
        else:
            ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(cipherletter.lower(), '_')
            ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(cipherletter.upper(), '_')
            key = ''.join(key)

# With the key we've created, decrypt the ciphertext.

return simpleSubCipher.decryptMessage(key, ciphertext)
```

Comment: In Python, strings are immutable, so you can't change their characters in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Because `key` is type of `str`.

In Python, strings does not support item assignment like a list (as the error message explicitly said).

To update the character of a string to a given index, you can do something like:

```
string = "foobar"
charindex = 2 # so you wants to replace the second "o"
print(string[0:charindex] + 'O' + string[charindex+1:])
# gives foObar
```

Or turn it in function:

```
def replace_at_index(string, replace, index):
    return string[0:index] + replace + string[index+1:]

print(replace_at_index('EggsandBacon', 'A', 4))
# gives EggsAndBacon
```

So you will use it like:

```
key = replace_at_index(key, cipherletter, keyIndex)
```

Comment: `''.join(...)` is overkill when you can just `string[:charindex] + "O" + string[charindex+1:]`

Comment: pretty sure `+` on strings is bad practice (it's directly bound to C `+`, so it will not works with jython or stuff like that)

Comment: That's... not true at all. C doesn't even have `+` on strings and if it did that would still have no bearing on the implementation of `+` in Python

Comment: Yes, I just realized how what I said is wrong, sry. But I still remember `+` on strings is not a good practice (but can't find any source ..). Well, will continue to search tonight and update my answer if needed. Anyway, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you've got an indentation error. Instead of:

```
# First create a simple sub key from the letterMapping mapping.
    key = ['x'] * len(LETTERS)
    for cipherletter in LETTERS:
        if len(letterMapping[cipherletter]) == 1:
# If there's only one letter, add it to the key.
            keyIndex = LETTERS.find(letterMapping[cipherletter][0])
            key[keyIndex] = cipherletter
        else:
            ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(cipherletter.lower(), '_')
            ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(cipherletter.upper(), '_')
            key = ''.join(key)
```

you should have:

```
# First create a simple sub key from the letterMapping mapping.
keyList = ['x'] * len(LETTERS)

for cipherletter in LETTERS:
    if len(letterMapping[cipherletter]) == 1:
        # If there's only one letter, add it to the key.
        keyIndex = LETTERS.find(letterMapping[cipherletter][0])
        keyList[keyIndex] = cipherletter
    else:
        ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(cipherletter.lower(), '_')
        ciphertext = ciphertext.replace(cipherletter.upper(), '_')

key = ''.join(keyList)
```

The deeper problem is that you're using `key`, in your original code, at *both* a string *and* a list. Obviously that's confusing, as witness the fact that you ended up confused! In my version, above, I separated these into two different variables, which I think you'll find clearer.